# Program returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I try to fill out a form but it only returns undefined. There will be more codes in the array.

```js
var codes = ["OHLV-NF12-KTV7-VELO-QPX5"]
var i = 0;
while(i>codes.length){
document.getElementsByClassName('redeem-input-text-box id-track-click')[0].value=codes[i];
i++
}
```

Comment: 0 is not greater than the length of `codes`. Plus, you're not showing anything that has a return statement.

Comment: it should be as `while (i < codes.length)`

Comment: @krillgar I tried to change ´while(i>10)´but it doesn't work.

Comment: Because you just set `i = 0`. 0 will never be greater than any non-negative number.

Comment: but i is `i++` at the end of while

Comment: Keep while(i<10) and then check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**var i=0**  and **codes.length=1** when use **while(i>codes.length){** never run code Because 0 is not greater than 1 .

So ,

Change :

```
 while(i>codes.length){
```

To :

```
 while(i<codes.length){
```

Example :

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
    <p class="redeem"></p>
        <script>
            var codes = ["OHLV-NF12-KTV7-VELO-QPX5"];
            var i = 0;
            while(i<codes.length){
            document.getElementsByClassName("redeem")[0].innerHTML=codes[i];
            i++
            }
        </script>
    </body>     
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the loop index is smaller than the length. But, it doesn't make sense for something to return `undefined` here. Maybe your element is not a HTML input.

---

```
var codes = ["OHLV-NF12-KTV7-VELO-QPX5"];

var i = 0,
    len = codes.length;

var field = document.getElementsByClassName('redeem-input-text-box id-track-click')[0];

while(i < len){
    field.value = codes[i];
    i ++;
}
```

Anyway, `for` looks more simple:

```
for(expression; condition exp; action exp)
```

so:

```
for(var i = 0, len = codes.length; i < len; i ++) {
    field.value = codes[i];
}
```